# i have an error in my python code key error ['logo_url'] not in index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, plotly-dash, keyerror, yfinance

```
def update_data(n, val):  # inpur parameter(s)
    if n == None:
        return "Hey there! Please enter a legitimate stock code to get details.", "https://melmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Screen-Shot-2019-07-31-at-5.47.12-PM.png", "Stonks", None, None, None
        # raise PreventUpdate
    else:
        if val == None:
            raise PreventUpdate
        else:
            ticker = yf.Ticker(val)
            inf = ticker.info
            df = pd.DataFrame().from_dict(inf, orient="index").T
            df[["logo_url", "shortName", "longBusinessSummary"]]
            return df['logo_url'].values[0], df['shortName'].values[
                0], df['longBusinessSummary'].values[0], None, None, None
```

In this code I get an error...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SK\Desktop\stock-dash\app.py", line 122, in update_data
    df[["logo_url", "shortName", "longBusinessSummary"]]
  File "C:\Users\SK\Desktop\stock-dash\Project\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3767, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns._get_indexer_strict(key, "columns")[1]
  File "C:\Users\SK\Desktop\stock-dash\Project\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 5876, in _get_indexer_strict
    self._raise_if_missing(keyarr, indexer, axis_name)
  File "C:\Users\SK\Desktop\stock-dash\Project\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 5938, in _raise_if_missing
    raise KeyError(f"{not_found} not in index")
KeyError: "['logo_url'] not in index"
```

I want it's solution please help me

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the line `df[["logo_url", "shortName", "longBusinessSummary"]]` is intended to select specific columns from the DataFrame, but it is missing an assignment statement to store the selected columns.

To fix the error, you need to assign the selected columns back to the df variable. Here's the corrected code:

```
def update_data(n, val):

    if n is None:
        return (
            "Hey there! Please enter a legitimate stock code to get details.",
            "https://melmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Screen-Shot-2019-07-31-at-5.47.12-PM.png",
            "Stonks",
            None,
            None,
            None,
        )
    else:
        if val is None:
            raise PreventUpdate
        else:
            ticker = yf.Ticker(val)
            inf = ticker.info
            df = pd.DataFrame().from_dict(inf, orient="index").T
            df = df[["logo_url", "shortName", "longBusinessSummary"]]  # Assign selected columns back to df
            return (
                df['logo_url'].values[0],
                df['shortName'].values[0],
                df['longBusinessSummary'].values[0],
                None,
                None,
                None,
            )
```